# LibreOffice: bubble text suggestion won't go away

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Writer I get word suggestions in a text bubble. I have switched off "tips" in Tools/Options/LibreOffice/General. What can I do to remove this very annoying bubble text?

[image: pic]

In the screen shot the bubble is gray, on my screen is almost black. The specific word is in Dutch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like word completion to me. You should be able to disable it by navigating to *Tools* → *AutoCorrect Options...* → *Word Completion* and unchecking *Enable word completion*.

Source:

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/4600/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-predictive-text-feature/